# Prove tautological consequence from a set of premises question

Tags: logic

For this problem, I am asked to provide an informal proof to show that whether **if** $S$ is a tautological consequence of $P_1, . . . , P_n$, then the set of sentences {$S, P_1, . . . , P_n$} is consistent. I will appreciate it very much if anyone can verify my solution.

**Here is my attempt:**

A sentence $S$ is a tautological consequence of some premises $P_1, . . . , P_n$  if $S$ follows from the premises based on the meanings of the truth-functional connectives on a truth table. So, $S$ is a tautological consequence of the premises if and only if every row of their joint truth table that assigns true to each of the premises also assigns true to $S$. Thus, the premises must be consistent with each other to have a true value assigned to each of the premises. If the premises are inconsistent, for example, $P$ and $\neg P$, then there will be a contradiction of the premises and it is also impossible to assign a true value to each of the premises regardless of the truth value of the conclusion. So, in the case of inconsistent premises, $S$ will never be a tautological consequence of $P_1, . . . , P_n$. Therefore, if $S$ is a tautological consequence of $P_1, . . . , P_n$, then the set of sentences

{$S, P_1, . . . , P_n$} must be consistent.

**My Doubts:**

I understand what is required for $S$ to be tautological consequence of the premises, however, what happens if we have a truth table that has inconsistent premises, thus not a single row of the table has a True value assigned to each of the premises and the conclusion. What do we call this type of truth table? Is it a trivial logic?

Thanks

LZ

Comment: What is the definition of *consistent* set of formulas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is sound: there is a tricky point here.

We say that a formula $S$ is a [tautological consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_consequence) of a set $\{ P_1,\ldots,P_n \}$ of premises if:

> in all cases when all the propositions $P_{1},\ldots, P_{n}$ are *true*, also the proposition $S$ is *true*.

This amounts to saying that:

> $S$ is a *tautological consequence* of $\{ P_1,\ldots,P_n \}$ iff $\{ \lnot S,P_1,\ldots,P_n \}$ is *unsatisfiable* (or *inconsistent*).

But if the set $\{ \lnot S,P_1,\ldots,P_n \}$ is unsatisfiable, i.e. no truth assignment evaluates all the formulas to *true*, we have that every truth assignment taht evaluates all $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ to *true* must evaluate $\lnot S$ to *false*.

Thus, such an assignment will evaluate $S$ to *true*.

Is this enough to conclude that there must be a truth assignment that satisfies $\{ S,P_1,\ldots,P_n \}$ ?

Not necessarily: we may have **no** assignment evaluating to *true* all of $P_{1},\ldots, P_{n}$.

---

> What happens if we have a truth table that has inconsistent premises ?

If the set of premises $\{ P_1,\ldots,P_n \}$ is *inconsistent* (or *unsatisfiable*), we have that there is **no** assignment of truth values that can simultaneously satisfy them all.

But then, we can build a truth table with premises $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ and conclusion $S$ whatever and we have that in every row where all the premises are *true* (there is none) also the conclusion $S$ is.

This means that a formula $S$ whatever is *tautological consequence* of an inconsistent set of premises.

---

See also [Ex falso quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).